# Cannot access property of the first array subscript using React js

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of JSON strings:

listItems = [{Name: "test", Title:"test2"}, {Name: "test2", Title:"test4" }]

From my code I need to access the Name property of the first object in the array.

I tried:

```
console.log(listItems[0]);
```

which prints out the first object in the array.

But when I try

```
console.log(listItems[0].Name);
```

it gives me an error that it cannot access the `name` property of null. How can I access a property of the first subscript?

Comment: listItems[0]['Name']

Comment: It should work actually, check whether you do some mutations along the way, or having some side effects or post the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
listItems = [{Name: "test", Title:"test2"}, {Name: "test2", Title:"test4" }]

console.log(listItems[0]['Name'] );
```

Comment: I just answered to see what will happen. :) ᖘ, I am not sure how to duplicate.